# Interface stub with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have been reading the test doubles section of phpunit manual to figure out if it is possible to create an stub from an interface.
I need to fake an call to a method from an object which implements an interface but I don't want to create a fake class for that.
Is it a way to create an instance of object that implements an interface without actually having a class definition of such an object?

The code below isn't working but may be helpful to understand what I am trying to achieve,
Thanks in advance guys

```
/**
* @test
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
*/
public function searchAlbumThrowExceptionWhenDataBaseConnectionFailed(){
    $albumRepositoryStub = $this->getMock('AlbumFinder\Repository\AlbumRepositoryInterface');

    $albumRepositoryStub->method('fetchPage')
    ->will( $this->throwException(new \Exception()));

    //code
}
```

Comment: PHPUnit mocks do work with interfaces. Please give us details on the error you're getting.

Comment: this is the error i see when run the test: Call to undefined method Mock_AlbumRepositoryInterface_ae3e29c9::method()
I have try to explicitly set the method when create the mock like this: $albumRepositoryStub = $this->getMock('AlbumFinder\Repository\AlbumRepositoryInterface', array('fetchPage')); i am still getting the same error.- Here's the interface declaration:                              interface AlbumRepositoryInterface {
 const ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE = 5;
 
 public function fetchPage($searchTerm='',$pageNumber=0,$elementsPerPage=self::ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE);
}

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need that the interface is autoloaded. Check that by calling:

```
$this->assertTrue(interface_exists('AlbumFinder\Repository\AlbumRepositoryInterface'));
```

just at the start of the test.

If the interface loads, check that the method name is correct. Other than that it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem with my code. I was missing the 'expects' method call when mocking the interface method. This is the code that is working for me now:
$albumRepositoryStub = $this->getMock('AlbumFinder\Repository\AlbumRepositoryInterface');

```
    $albumRepositoryStub->expects($this->any())
    ->method('fetchPage')
    ->will( $this->throwException(new \Exception()));
```